# installArchives() error when installing Eclipse IDE in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, chromebook

I installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook via Crouton so I could code on it. Everything's been working pretty well up until I tried to run: 
`umake ide eclipse`
I installed Ubuntu Make to help install Eclipse, but when I run the above command I get an installArchives() error:

```
  Choose installation path: /home/user/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse
  Downloading and installing requirements
  ERROR: installArchives() failed
  Subprocess output: dkpg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
  dpkp: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
  dpkp: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
  Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

 100% |##########################################################################|
 Error: Package requirements can't be met: installArchives() failed
 Subprocess output: dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
 dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
 dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
 Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/loca/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
 E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

apologies if most of this is unnecessary code, I'm not experienced with terminal usage and don't quite understand most things yet. Thanks for any help!